# What is the use of tags in SVN?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you use the svn tags directory for anyways?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941646/what-do-you-use-the-svn-tags-directory-for-anyways)

In SVN i understand the usage of "trunk and branches" in the repository but I still cannot understand the use of "tags" in the repository of SVN. Please explain it clearly

Comment: There's a whole section on tags in the Subversion book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Answer (score 0):

Tags are often used to mark important stages in development, for example if you make a release of your software you might choose to tag the version that made up that release. This practice can help with keeping track of bug and features - if you want to know whether a particular bug was fixed in v3.2.1 of your application you can just check the tag that you made for that release and see what code was shipped at that time.